# proof of normal equations for ordinary least squares using matrix trace

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, linear-regression

I follow the proof [on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_ordinary_least_squares#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations). However, I first encountered this while looking at [these notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) from Stanford CS229. Section 2.2 contains a proof that uses matrix traces, including this part from page 11:

[image: proof]

I'm not clear on the fourth step. I understand that tr(A+B) = trA + trB, so the first term in the parentheses is clear. However, I don't follow how the trace of the other three terms are combined into:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last term in the parentheses $y^Ty$ does not involve $\theta$ so its derivative (with respect to $\theta$) is zero. This is why it disappears on the fourth line.

The two terms before it have the same trace because for a matrix $A$, we have $\text{tr} A^T=\text{tr}  A$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I hadn't thought that far because the derivatives for the other terms weren't being taken until the subsequent step.